# How to install extra packages -want Konsole

Tags: konsole

In Ubuntu 13.04, how do i add more apps, like Konsole, and where do i get them. I bought a laptop running Ubuntu 13.04, and the usual commands don't work in Gnome-Terminal. Whould i reinstall?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Do you want to know how to install *an specific app* or to know what is the correct procedure/s for *every application*? Would you like to show us the commands that you're trying by now?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that you can install applications under Ubuntu, some of the ways that you can use are:

- Use the Ubuntu Software Center

[image]

- Use Synaptic

To install synaptic, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

For more information check out [Installing Software](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware)